# Gradle cannot find symbol for android support v4

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am migrating an Android project that used to use Maven for dependency management to Gradle.

I am new to Gradle and I am having a problem where Gradle cannot compile the project because it fails saying that it cannot find a bunch of symbols, and all of them are methods that are part of the support-v4 library.

I think I added the dependencies correctly, as I followed a bunch of tutorials. The way they are listed in my build.gradle file is like so:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile (
        'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1',
        'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1',
        'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1',
        'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1',
        'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0',
        'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3',
        'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2',
        'br.com.estudio89:sentry:1.0-SNAPSHOT',
        'br.com.estudio89:syncing:1.0.17',
        'br.com.estudio89:push_messaging:1.0.3',
        'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.9',
        'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2',
        'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5',
        'joda-time:joda-time:2.7',
        'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.5.1',
        'com.facebook.rebound:rebound:0.3.8',
        'commons-net:commons-net:3.3',
        files("src/main/libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar")
    )

}
```

I have spent many hours trying to figure this out but I can't.

One of the errors I get when trying to build the project from the command line is as follows:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        menuSettings = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings));
                                     ^
  symbol:   method getActionView(MenuItem)
  location: class MenuItemCompat
```

What am I doing wrong? Maven can compile the project just fine with the same set of dependencies.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you try clean build or gradle clean ? fiels looks to be fine.

Comment: I did... I am building it in the command line with `gradle clean build`

Comment: Use higher version of builttool like 23.0.1

Comment: I am actually using version 23.0.2 so I guess that's not it...

Comment: I may have figured out what the problem is. Android Studio is showing me that the library `com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar` has support-v4 as a dependency (included in the library as a jar). I was aware of that and because of it I had added the `exclude module: 'support-v4'` to that dependency. However, it seems that that exclusion is not working and gradle is actually compiling this old version of the support library instead of the one I am actually specifying in the build.gradle file... Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out...

The dependency `com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar` has support-v4 as a dependency (included in the library as a jar). I was aware of that and because of it I had added the line `exclude module: 'support-v4'` to that dependency. However, it seems that that exclusion was not working and gradle was actually compiling this old version of the support library instead of the one I am actually specifying in the `build.gradle` file.

What I did was I switched from using the library hosted on github to this other repo: `fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1`

I guess it is an error that's very specific to my project but I decided to post this here just in case other people run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
 compile ('com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
```

**This kind of exclusion doesn't work.**
You are getting this library from the jitpack.
[This library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) **adds the support library as a jar** and not as a gradle dependency.

It means that the pom file doesn't have a dependency and you can't exclude the jar file with gradle because the jar is inside the aar file (without a pom how can gradle know that these files should be excluded?).

You can check the files in the jitpack repo:

- [pom file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1.pom)
- [aar file](https://jitpack.io/com/github/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/2.4.1/ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1.aar)